# Flutter - loop not working while parsing json

Tags: flutter, api, loops, dart

I am trying to create model and parse json data from api

for that i created the model class you can see below

```
class FeatureModel {
  String? PlanFeatures;
  bool? FeatureStatus;

  FeatureModel({this.PlanFeatures, this.FeatureStatus});


  FeatureModel.fromJson(parsonJson) {
    PlanFeatures = parsonJson['PlanFeatures'];
    FeatureStatus = parsonJson['FeatureStatus'];
  }
}
```

now i am trying to parse json with the help of loop

let me show you my method

```
List<FeatureModel> featureModel = [];

Uri featureAPI = Uri.parse(
    planFeatureApi);
apiCall() async {
  try {
    http.Response response = await http.get(featureAPI);
    // print(response.statusCode);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var decode = json.decode(response.body);
      print(decode);
      for (var i = 0; i < decode.length; i++) {
        print(i);
        featureModel.add(
          FeatureModel.fromJson(decode[i]),
        );
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {}
}
```

I am calling it here

```
 onPressed: () async{
                      await  apiCall();
}
```

but the problem is here
loop is not working while parsing data
in that particular code i remains on 0 only

when i removes  `featureModel.add( FeatureModel.fromJson(decode[i]), );` i started increaing till 10

please let me know if i am making any mistake or what
thanks in advance

Here is the sample of api respone

```
[{"PlanFeatures":"Video Link Sharing","FeatureStatus":"true"},{"PlanFeatures":"Email \u0026amp; Telephonic Support","FeatureStatus":"true"},{"PlanFeatures":"Remove Pixeshare Branding","FeatureStatus":"false"},{"PlanFeatures":"Add Custom logo on uploaded photos","FeatureStatus":"false"},{"PlanFeatures":"Get Visitor Info","FeatureStatus":"false"},{"PlanFeatures":"Mobile Apps","FeatureStatus":"false"},{"PlanFeatures":"Send Questionnaries","FeatureStatus":"false"},{"PlanFeatures":"Create \u0026amp; Send Quotation","FeatureStatus":"false"},{"PlanFeatures":"Online Digital Album Sharing","FeatureStatus":"false"},{"PlanFeatures":"Analytics","FeatureStatus":"false"}]
```

thanks

Comment: can you give us a sample of the response

Comment: @Gwhyyy yes i have updated it

Answer (score 0):

I found many errors, first, the fromJson is not a `factory` constructor and doesn't return a class instance from the JSON.
the second one is that the bool values from the sample you added are `String` not a `bool` so we need to check over it.

try changing your model class to this:

```
 class FeatureModel {
  String? PlanFeatures;
  bool? FeatureStatus;

  FeatureModel({this.PlanFeatures, this.FeatureStatus});

  factory FeatureModel.fromJson(parsonJson) {
    return FeatureModel(
      PlanFeatures: parsonJson['PlanFeatures'],
      FeatureStatus: parsonJson['FeatureStatus'] == "false" ? false : true,
    );
  }
}
```